# can't change the folder name which fetched by this ftp program

Tags: python, ftp

I download a folder through this program,,the folder has several files and a subfolder,,when i use os.rename to change the name of downloaded folder ,it did not work,,when i trying delete the folder,,it says the subfolder being is used....I am sure something is wrong with this program,,But I don't know where

```
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-
import os
import config
import sys
import ftplib

class FTPSync(object):
    def __init__(self, remote_dir="/", local_dir='./'):
    self.conn = ftplib.FTP()
    self.conn.connect(host=config.ftp_ip, port=config.ftp_port)
    self.conn.login(user=config.ftp_user, passwd=config.ftp_passwd)
    self.conn.cwd(remote_dir)        

    if not os.path.exists(local_dir):
        os.makedirs(local_dir)
    os.chdir(local_dir)

def get_dirs_files(self):

    dir_res = []
    self.conn.dir('.', dir_res.append)
    files = [f.split(None, 8)[-1] for f in dir_res if f.startswith('-')]
    dirs = [f.split(None, 8)[-1] for f in dir_res if f.startswith('d')]
    return (files, dirs)

def walk(self, next_dir):
    self.conn.cwd(next_dir)
    try:
        os.mkdir(next_dir)
    except OSError:
        pass
    os.chdir(next_dir)

    ftp_curr_dir = self.conn.pwd()
    local_curr_dir = os.getcwd()

    files, dirs = self.get_dirs_files()
    for f in files:
        retry_cnt = 10
        while retry_cnt > 0:
            outf = open(f, 'wb')
            try:
                self.conn.retrbinary('RETR %s' % f, outf.write)
            finally:
                o_size = outf.tell()
                outf.close()
            r_size = self.conn.size(f)
            if o_size == r_size:
                break
            else:
                retry_cnt -= 1
        if retry_cnt == 0:
            print f,"download fail"
            return False
    for d in dirs:
        os.chdir(local_curr_dir)
        self.conn.cwd(ftp_curr_dir)
        self.walk(d)

    return True
def run(self):
    return self.walk('.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
ftp = FTPSync()
ftp.run()
```

Comment: Please add a comment in the code which shows us where it breaks.

Comment: Based on the error messages, the target ftp server seems to be running on a Windows machine. If anyone is using a folder on the Windows, Windows will stop you from renaming or removing the folder. There is nothing your ftp client can do about.

Comment: @AnthonyKong you are totally right! this program works fine in linux,but in window it still do not work..s when i quote the ftp part,,it can rename the folder,,so i am sure it is ftp still using the folder,,so how can i release it